# Error in Importing sharepoint site data into sql database table

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When I try to import sharepoint site's data into my SQL table it inserts junk datas like "","","" these junk datas are added with my string.

I import data from sharepoint site using webpart,I insert the data in my database table through webpart which uses a StoredProcedure.

The only thing which I can do is Replace the junk datas with ""(Empty space)
if possible Please do help me to remove those junk datas without using Replace function

The stored procedure uses
 exec opendocument xml & 
removedocument xml

Comment: not enough info, and i'm pretty sure you're not using both mysql and sql-server

Comment: am using sql server @Tanner

Comment: is there any other info dat I can provide u?

Comment: Tell us about the web part that uses the stored procedure (What type of web part is it? How is it configured?), tell us about the data you're trying to import (is it from a SharePoint list? Is it other SharePoint information?), and tell us about the stored procedure that's being called (post the code if possible).